# Questions about randomizing script

Tags: javascript

So today I got interested in learning a script that randomizes each letter/number, such as 0000-0000 and each 0 gets randomized by random letter or number. In my previous post I asked about how to do it and got the script, however; the problem I'm having now is completely understanding the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function randomised(len) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    }

    function randomiseString(str){
        var charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var _str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function(a){
            return charSet[randomised(charSet.length)]
        });
        return _str;
    }

    $('.combination').text(function(i,t){
        return randomiseString(t);
    });

});
```

So this is the code, and here are some of the stuff I'm wondering about:

```
var _str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function(a){
    return charSet[randomised(charSet.length)]
});
```

1) So this is the main part that makes the randomization. I'm now having perhaps silly thoughts but I'm wondering how can I force upper-case all the letters I've set above. I know I could just replace those letters with upper-case letters, but I'd like to know how can I do it with code. Also if I understand correctly it makes the charSet an array?

```
var _str = str.replace(/[^-]/g,function(a)
```

2) Why does the function have (a) value? Does it make any difference weather I leave it blank or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Javascript does have documentation. Googling for "mdn uppercase" tells you the answer to 1).

Comment: You’re right, the `(a)` parameter isn’t used. You can take it out safely.

Comment: $millimoose - The problem I'm having is that "charSet[]" is in array I, right? And also what if the random string is a number and it's trying to upper-case it?

@minitech - So do some coders have habit why they enter value inside function like this?

Comment: @Martastico: It’s because the function *can* actually take a parameter (the match). In `replace`, you usually end up using it, but in this case, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't require that the parameters passed to a function match the parameters expected by the function at all. This means that you can safely omit the parameters to any function if you don't need them, and in the code above, instead of

```
function (a) {
    // code that doesn't use a
}
```

you could use

```
function () {
    // ...
}
```